# Simple Java Swing Animation Lag

Tags: java, swing

I am a java beginner and I'm having trouble with a simple swing animation I created. The animation lags when running unless something else is happening like mouse movement or a key being pressed down. I have searched for answers but none of them solve this problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
    int y = 0, velY = 2;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        y += velY;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(50, y, 50, 50);

        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animation drawPanel = new Animation();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(drawPanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, get that `timer.start()` **out** of your paintComponent method since it does not belong there, and serves no purpose other than to slow the rendering down. Instead you should call that method once, and once only.

Next, 5 mSecs may be an unrealistic timer delay. Experiment with this number, but expect to get a decent functioning somewhere near 10 to 15 mSecs.

Next, base your position change on actual time slice differences that have been measured, not on what you're hoping the timer is doing.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Animation extends JPanel {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 16;
    private static final double Y_VELOCITY = 0.05;
    private double dY = 0.0;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());

    public Animation() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(50, (int) dY, 50, 50);
        // timer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        private long prevTime;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (prevTime == 0L) {
                repaint();
                prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long deltaTime = currentTime - prevTime;
                double deltaY = Y_VELOCITY * deltaTime;
                dY += deltaY;
                prevTime = currentTime;
                repaint();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animation drawPanel = new Animation();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(drawPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: As for timer frequency, the minimum sensible timer delay for painting in Swing is 1000/60=16.6, round down to 16ms. The reasoning behind this is that the average desktop display device refreshes at 60hz, making updates faster than the actual display refreshes is surely invisible to the user, and thus superflous.

Comment: @Durandal: thanks for that information -- I never knew that! I'd like to add that to my answer if OK.